# Detecting idle time in JavaScript across Tabs?

Tags: javascript

I have written a script which detects the idle time in javascript and logs out user after 30 mins of inactivity. The script runs fine. But one thing where it will fail is if the user opens any of the page in new tab and is working on that page. The script on previous tab will still run and log the user out of both the tabs. What could be possible solution to preserve the idle time detection across Tabs.

```
var time = new Date().getTime();
                $(document.body).bind("mousemove keypress", function(e) {
                    time = new Date().getTime();
                });
```

```
     function refresh() {
         if(new Date().getTime() - time >= 6000) {
             $('#edit-quote-details').modal('show');
         clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(61,{
                clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
                countdown: true,
                callbacks: {
                    stop: function() {
                        window.location.href='../logout.action';
                    }
                }
            });
         }
         else {
             setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
         }
     }

     setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
```

Comment: How about continuously saving a timestamp of the last activity in some form of local storage as long as the user is active. You can then check that timestamp to see if the user has been active on your site, in any tab, and if the timestamp is more than 30 minutes old, log out the user.

Comment: Thinking of localstorage wouldnt it also work for pages opened in new windows same browser. In that case that behaviour should not be there? What do u think.

Comment: Yes, a local storage would be the same no matter if you are in a new window or just in a new tab in the same window. Does that really matter though? I mean, a tab can easily be detached from a window and be turned into a window of its own. In my opinion you shouldn't see new tabs and new windows as different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For older browsers, I would use the Observer pattern to communicate across tabs (as long as the tabs have been opened by a common parent).

If HTML5 is an option (ie: modern browsers only), you can use local storage. If you go that route, I would explore local forage from Mozilla since that might have a shim for older browsers.

If you want something that is a cross-browser solution, you will need to use the server to track that.

Update:
You can also post messages across documents in different domains using Cross-document Messaging.

API Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage
Example: http://html5demos.com/postmessage2

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to implement this functionality on my clients website. Didnt find any idleal solution for this in web.Finally I had to twig my code,think of some logic and implement this.The code goes as below--

```
     `/*Put this code inside script tag whereever you want to execute the inactivity popup*/
     var t;
    //set the timeout period  
    var timeoutPeriod = '${inactiveIntervalMillis}';  
    //detect various events  
    callUserEvents();  
     `

//remove the logged Out storage after popup is closed by user  
function removeLocalStorage() {  
localStorage.removeItem("loggedOut");  
}      
//call this function whenever we detect user activity  
function resetUserActivity() {  
resetTimer();  
}  
//If the user is logged out and it clicks on other tabs,the popup will be               displayed there too  
function checkIfUserLoggedOut() {  
    if (localStorage.getItem("loggedOut")) {  
        loadLoginModal("/includes/gadgets/popup-content.jsp", 400, 230,  
            undefined);  
    }  
}  

// Call this method when any window onloads,this helps to check if multiple         tabs are opened by same site  
function incrementCounter() {   
    checkIfUserLoggedOut();  
    if (localStorage.getItem("counter") == "NaN") {  
        localStorage.setItem("counter", "0");  
    } else {  
        var counter = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("counter")) + 1;  
        localStorage.setItem("counter", counter);  
    }  
    resetTimer();  
}  
//after time interval,this method will be called  
function handleIdleTimedOut() {  
//get the current localStorage Object  
    window.sharedCounter = localStorage.getItem("counter");  
//If no tabs are opened,then popup will be shown here.  
    if (window.localCounter == window.sharedCounter) {  
        loadLoginModal("/includes/gadgets/popup-content.jsp", 400,               230,undefined);  
        localStorage.setItem("loggedOut", "true");  
    }   
}  

function resetTimer() {  
//save counterin current Window object,and after timeout period you can     match   it,if by chance multiple tabs were opened,the counter will be     different,popup  wont be shown in current window at incorrect time.  
    window.localCounter = localStorage.getItem("counter");  
    clearTimeout(t);  
    t = setTimeout(handleIdleTimedOut, timeoutPeriod);  
}  
function callUserEvents(){  
window.onload=incrementCounter  
window.onscroll = resetUserActivity;  
window.onmousemove = resetUserActivity;    
window.ondblclick = resetUserActivity;  
window.oncontextmenu = resetUserActivity;  
window.onclick = resetUserActivity;  
window.onkeypress = resetUserActivity;  
window.onpageshow = resetUserActivity;  
window.onresize = resetUserActivity;  
window.onfocus = incrementCounter;  
window.ondrag = resetUserActivity;  
window.oncopy = resetUserActivity;  
window.oncut = resetUserActivity;  
window.onpaste = resetUserActivity;     
}  

`
```